# Can not create vertical labels using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

using following code, I can get labels using geom_text but they are not vertical, even after I change angle to 90.

```
 p1 <- ggplot(segment(p)) +
         geom_segment(aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend),colour="blue") + labs(y = "Label y") +
         theme_classic()+theme(axis.line.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank()) + 
         geom_text(data=leaf_label_data, aes(x=xend, y=yend,label=label,angle = 90))
```

Comment: Can you please make this into a reproducible example? It's especially important for graphing questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try removing `angle=90` from the aes statement.

Answer (score 5):

You added `angle = 90` to `aes()` but it is no aesthetic. Just move it out of `aes` and it should work.

A simple example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), angle = 90, hjust = -0.1)
```